# Manage Enum field

Tags: c#, enums

I have an `enum`:

```
public enum Enumeration
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

And a method that takes one argument of type `Enumeration`:

```
public void method(Enumeration e)
{
}
```

I want that `method` can accept only `A` and `B` (`C` is considered a wrong value), but I need `C` in my `Enumeration` because other methods can accept it as right value. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might be interested in something like this: [Enum subsets in C#](http://trystans.blogspot.com/2011/01/enum-subsets-in-c.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't reject *just* `C`. I would reject *any value other than `A` and `B`*:

```
if (e != Enumeration.A && e != Enumeration.B)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("e");
}
```

This is important, as otherwise people could call:

```
Method((Enumeration) -1);
```

and it would pass your validation. You always need to be aware that an enum is really just a set of named integers - but *any* integer of the right underlying type can be cast to the enum type.

Comment: Why use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of `ArgumentException`?

Comment: @gliderkite: Because it fits, I would say. It's "outside the allowable range" just as the exception description states. Note that `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` extends `ArgumentException`, so it's still an `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 5):

Throw an exception:

```
public void method(Enumeration e)
{
    if (e != Enumeration.A && e != Enumeration.B) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("e");
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher then you could use [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx).

Comment: A note: `Contract` is valid only for .NET Framework 4 or higher.

Comment: That's a somewhat strange comparison, why not simply use `!=`?

Comment: @EdS.: I think it's easier to read "not (a or b)" than "not a and not b", but I can change it if you care about it.

Comment: @MarkByers: Haha, no, no need to change your style for me, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

As paulsm4 mentioned, you can define:

```
public enum EnumSubset
{
    A = Enumeration.A,
    B = Enumeration.B,
}
```

And use:

```
public void method(EnumSubset e)
{
}
```